# What triggers the partial re-index on attribute mass update?

Tags: product, catalog, indexing, reindex, flat-catalog

I'm having a hard time figuring out what fires off the flat table update (partial re-indexing) when a attribute mass update is done from the Manage Catalog page in the admin.

When you mass-update attributes from the admin, the following methods are called in order.

1. `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Action_AttributeController::saveAction`
2. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action::updateAttributes`
3. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Action::updateAttributes`

You can go straight to `3` to use the mass-update functionality, but the update doesn't propagate to the flat table. So, one would think it's something before `3` that triggers the re-indexing, but it's not clear what.

At first glance, `2` has

```
// register mass action indexer event
Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
    $this, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_MASS_ACTION
);
```

which looks like the answer, but the flat table is updated even with this commented out. I've even tried reducing `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action::updateAttributes` down to 
the following, but it still re-indexes.

```
public function updateAttributes($productIds, $attrData, $storeId)
{
    $this->_getResource()->updateAttributes($productIds, $attrData, $storeId);

    return $this;
}
```

Any idea what actually updates the flat table when attribute mass update is done in the admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save` triggers the observer to initiate reindexing of the products updated in the mass-update.